# Alertdialog with setcontentview

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I want to create a custom alertdialog.So i used the following code.

```
public class MyAlertDialog extends AlertDialog {

    protected MyAlertDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.show();
        setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);
    }
}
```

**logindialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/layoutgrey" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mediuem"
        android:text="username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mediuem"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mediuem"
        android:text= Password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mediuem"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Ok" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

so when i try to use the custom created button like this

```
final MyAlertDialog alert = new MyAlertDialog(Home.this);
alert.show();
Button ok=(Button)alert.findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button cancel=(Button)alert.findViewById(R.id.button2);

ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

It says nullpointer exception.
Please help to figure out whats wrong here.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's a custom Yes-No dialog. It's similar to what you are trying to achieve. You can easily adapt it to your layout.

Inflate your custom layout in the constructor

Find your `Button` by its Id

Set the `Button`'s `OnClickListener` : inside `onClick()` call an abstract method that you will need to implement later on.

```
public abstract class YesNoDialog extends Dialog 
{
    private String mMessage = "";
    private TextView mText;
    private Button mYes;
    private Button mNo;

    public YesNoDialog(Context context, String message)
    {
        super(context);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yes_no_dialog, null);
        mText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);
        mMessage = message;
        mText.setText(mMessage);
        mYes = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.yes);
        mYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                dismiss();
                onYes();
            }
        });
        mNo = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.no);
        mNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                dismiss();
                onNo();
            }
        });
        setCancelable(false);
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        setContentView(v);
    }

    public abstract void onYes();

    public abstract void onNo();

}
```

And this is how to use it:

```
YesNoDialog dialog = new YesNoDialog(this, "message")
{

    @Override
    public void onYes()
    {
      // do something           
    }

    @Override
    public void onNo()
    {
      // do something
    }
};
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're certainly doing some overengineering, just call `setView()` with your custom `View` on the `AlertDialog's` `Builder`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 your getting null pointer exception because your directly trying to access the layout.
 tryout some like this

// in case your in activity class
setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.logindialog,null));

// in case of other than activity pass the context and use it like this 

  setContentView(((LayoutInflator)context.getSystemService(     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.logindialog,null));
```